# Nvchad running linters without me installing them

Tags: configuration, neovim, neovim-plugin

I recently shifted from VScode to neovim, and I used NVChad for the quick setup. I installed all lsps using mason and I didn't install any linters but on using neovim, pylint is already running over my code.

[Image showing pylint is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqgiP.png)

[Mason showing no linter were installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dLus.png)

I tried googling stuff and going through NVChad documentation but couldn't find any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I was using python-language-server which automatically enables linter if available (https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your nvim/lua/custom/configs/lspconfig.lua and look at

```lua
local servers = { }
```

Maybe pylint is there, if that doesn't help try to reinstalling NVChad